# Ubuntu 20.04 installation gave my terminal all squares with 4 characters in them

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome-terminal, encoding

After installation of Ubuntu 20.04 my terminal characters shifted to some kind of squares with hex codes in them. I am not able to find out how to get back to normal. Any suggestions?

[image: Terminal snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by going into **Preferences > Compatibility** and selected *Ambiguous-width characters: Wide*. It seems it was set to *Narrow*.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the upgrade, I'd selected a custom font in **Preferences > [Profile] > Text**, and ticked the *Custom Font* checkbox.

I suspect the upgrade retains the state of the checkbox but doesn't retain the font selected.

Simply selecting a custom font or unchecking the Custom Font checkbox worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings > Profile > Text > Customize** to choose the font you want.