# I cannot read anything from the terminal in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal

The terminal is in very weird characters after I installed Ubuntu 20.04. Below is an image of how it looks.
If I copy the text to search the problem, it is converted back to normal text.

The texts looks like some special characters:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you go in the Terminal preferences and set a different Mono font? I would try to run the commands "sudo fc-cache -f && sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig" in order to regenerate the fonts cache with a copy-paste, but you won't be able to read the outputs of the commands...

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239784/help-ubuntu-20-04-installation-gave-my-terminal-all-squares-with-4-characters-i?rq=1

Comment: @LorenzKeel If you go to the terminal preferences and change the font, the font preview is in readable characters but the terminal window is still in those weird characters. And when I ran that command the result was:  `Regenerating fonts cache... done.`